# AttributeError: module 'drivefiller' has no attribute 'filler' When used as an installed library from pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me and my friend recently made this library as a bit of a joke called drive filler [(here it is on Github)](https://github.com/ConorMatthews/drivefiller). We uploaded this to the pypi.org and it originally worked as expected. Yesterday I updated it, tested it locally, then uploaded to Github before updating it on pip. Everything worked fine when the drivefiller.py file was in the local folder when using the below code, giving the expected result.

```
import drivefiller as df
Filler_Object = df.filler('/Users/conor/Desktop/', 'text', 'Hello World!', 0, 20)
Filler_Object.fill()
print(Filler_Object.checkSize())
```

However, when I deleted the local file, updated my installed version to the new one and tried to run it it gave the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/conor/Desktop/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    Filler_Object = df.filler('/Users/conor/Desktop/', 'text', 'Hello World!', 0, 20)
AttributeError: module 'drivefiller' has no attribute 'filler'
```

I have spent hours today trying to figure this out to no avail so any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Downloading you package from pip and looking at the GitHub repo, it's obvious you did not follow the [packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

You need would need to make a [proper module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/modules.html#packages), including an `__init__.py`, a `setup.py`, with all the proper definitions, which are currently missing from your project.
As a result, the current install from PyPi results in an almost empty `__init__.py` file containing only

```
name = "drivefiller"
```

Honestly, I don't even know how you got it on PyPi... and given the nature of your code, I'm not sure I'm doing anyone a favor by helping you put it on PyPi ^^"

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but it does only say in the tutorial you referenced in the first link (which was what i followed) to put `name = "drivefiller"` in the __init__.py file

Comment: Yeah... no, not really... but that's also why I put the second link ;)